# Which stored procedure using which view?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, view

**Description:**
My project have lots of stored procedure and also lots of views. I would like to know which stored procedure is using which view. Its quite hard, when i have lots of stored procedure.

I know there are some system table which I can use, but the system tables would not have information for the dynamic queries in my stored procedure.

Please let me know, how can i make it. Is there some tool, or stored procedure for the same. I want to see the relationship between my 'stored procedure' and 'views I used in my stored procedure'.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I normally use SQL Search from www.RedGate.com, when I want to search for dependencies, and other relations (such as copy-paste code)

Dynamic SQL is a problem because of its late binding.

HIH,

Henrik Staun Poulsen

Comment: I just now checked it and i think its not free. Is there some alternative or stored procedure which can provide me with such dependancies. If you have idea in case :)

Comment: According to www.red-gate.com; Currently SQL Search is a free tool, but we might charge for it in the future. If we do, the free version of SQL Search will still work.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is there a feature for the dynamic sql as well. I mean for understanding the relationships in case of dynamic sql. I am ready to invest some money of this feature is there :)

Comment: No, I do not think it is possible to create such a tool. How should it find 'MySproc', if my code creates it as 'My'+'S'+'proc'?
In addition to SQLSearch, I search our entire code base with SSMS. 
I have read-only copy of the code on the local drive.